# Not able to set multiple values in select2 dropdown after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 box for language selection. I am not able set selected values for edit language page

I tried to set manually all the values from array to select2

```
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
    $('#language').select2();  //key , value pair of language map
    var value = $('#langList').val(); // hidden list of id "[3,1,7]" value
    var result = value.substring(1, value.length-1);
    var res = result.split(","); // array of ids
    $('#language').val([res[0],res[1],res[2]]);
    $('#language').trigger('change');
});
```

Wanted to set all the values to select2. Please find html code below:

```
        <label for="language">Work Language:</label>
        <input type='hidden' value="${languageList}" id="langList"/>        
        <select name="language" id="language" multiple="multiple"> 
            <c:forEach items="${languageMap}" var="lang">
                 <option value="${lang.key}">${lang.value}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
```

Comment: Updated the html code